# Type is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicClassAttributes<>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Below is a render method. And I am using Typescript. I'm looping a x number of times to display multiple  React Components.

```
 render() {
    return (
        <div className="bleed">
            <ul className="list-door">
                {Array(this.numberOfDoors).fill(1).map((el, i) =>
                    <!-- line 28 --><li key={i}><Door id={i} ref={i}
                                      updateScoreHandler={this.props.updateScoreHandler}
                                      gameOverHandler={this.props.gameOverHandler}/>
                    </li>
                )}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The error I get is about the {Array(etc.etc.} Somehow the type is incorrect. How to fix this?

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/ListDoor.tsx:28:43

```
    TS2322: Type '{ id: number; ref: number; updateScoreHandler: (door: Door) => void; gameOverHandler: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Door> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode
; }> & Read...'.
  Type '{ id: number; ref: number; updateScoreHandler: (door: Door) => void; gameOverHandler: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicClassAttributes<Door>'.
    Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Ref<Door>'.
```

Answer (score 0):

`ref` needs to either be a string (*this is deprecated*) use `ref = {i.toString()}` or (preferably) a function: `ref = {x => /* whatever with x */}`.

It seems like you probably meant to write `key`, not `ref` here, based on this code?

Comment: Actually, I am using the ref attribute to later pass this.refs back to the parent component via a callback function.     componentDidMount() {
        this.props.registerChildComponentsHandler(this.refs);
    }

Comment: How would ref = {i.toString()} look with the function notation? Because ref = {i.toString()} works already fine.